# Authorization_RequestDenied getting Group Members

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the GraphServiceClient in my code to access multiple endpoints for data.

I have a GraphServiceClient (with delegated permissions) with the following scope: `Group.Read.All`.

I also have a GraphServiceClient (with application permissions) with the following scopes: `User.Read.All, Mail.Read`.

I first get a Group Id with the first client, no problems here. Then I use the Group id in the following code:

```
var users = await client
    .Groups[id]
    .Members
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Now the following scope is needed `Application - User.Read.All` which I have on my 2nd client but when I use this client to get the members of this group it gives the following message:

```
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied 
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Yes, the permissions are granted by an admin in AD and I use the "graphresource"/.default scope (works with getting just list users).

Do I also need `Directory.Read.All` (can't test that right now) or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have `User.Read.All` permission. `Group.Read.All` application permission will be enough for your 2nd client to get the members of this group.

Comment: So the documentation on their website is not correct?

Comment: @NLErik Of course `Directory.Read.Al` will ok. It has more permissions than both `User.Read.All` and `Group.Read.All`.

Comment: @NLErik `User.Read.All` permission isn't enough. I have tested this. Just let me know if you have any further concerns.

Comment: But why is this permission mentioned on the page, if it does not grant you access?

Comment: @NLErik Did you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs?

Comment: Yes. I did, will try the other permission at the end of the day.

Comment: @NLErik Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: No, just added the Directory.Read.All scope and it worked. But the documentation should be changed on the page..